# Apache Spark custom aggregation function

Tags: apache-spark

What is the best way to implement using Spark 2.0 the following query?

Aggregators? UDAF? Maybe there is already similar sparksql functionality?

```
select
  x, 
  sum(case when label='1' then 1 else 0 end) as p1,
  sum(1) as cnt
from
  df
group by
  x
```

Data:

```
x,label
---
a,1
a,1
a,0
b,1
b,0
b,0
c,0
c,1
c,0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.groupBy(['x']).agg(f.sum(f.when(df['label'] == '1', 1).otherwise(0)), f.count(df['x']))
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more on the answer. Just writing some code without (at least a short) explanation is usually not enough.